# No default value in sharedpreferences

Tags: android

A code snippet:

```
if (mGamePrefs.contains(GAME_PREF_NAME)) 
{
    theName = mGamePrefs.getString(GAME_PREF_NAME, "Jane Doe");
}
```

But when I retrieve the preference without any previous storage, there's no default value.
I do the retrieval with this code:

```
PreferenceLastGame gameSettings = new PreferenceLastGame(this);

String gameName  = gameSettings.getTheName();
```

I have to do this code to get my default value

```
if(gameName == null) gameName = "Jane Doe";
```

Every thing else is in place and works just fine.
Why is this failing?

GAME_PREF_NAME is define as:

```
public class MeMoInfoActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
public static final String GAME_PREF_NAME  = "TheName";         // key string
    ........
```

PreferenceLastGame is just a class where I put the code regarding the handling of preferences.

Comment: What is a `PreferenceLastGame`? Some more detail on your implementation of this and the `getTheName()` method might help. And also how you populate `mGamePrefs`.

Comment: Does GAME_PREF_NAME have quotes around it ?

Comment: GAME_PREF_NAME is defined as:

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mGamePrefs.contains(GAME_PREF_NAME)) 
{
    theName = mGamePrefs.getString(GAME_PREF_NAME, "Jane Doe");
}
```

You won't get a default value with this code. The first thing you do is check whether it contains `GAME_PREF_NAME`. If it doesn't, you skip the part where it *would* give it a default value.

Just use:

```
theName = mGamePrefs.getString(GAME_PREF_NAME, "Jane Doe");
```

Comment: Well at some time, life can be that simple.